# React-d3 Chart Not Showing

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-d3

I have performed the step by step instructions for getting a chart in **react-d3** :

http://www.reactd3.org/get_start/

I added this to my code and I see *nothing*.

However if I inspect then I do see an **SVG** tag with some things in it.

[image]

Has some element been flattened or do you need to set something up for displaying SVG in the browser?

My exact code looks like this :

```
import React from 'react';

var Chart = require('react-d3-core').Chart;
var LineChart = require('react-d3-basic').LineChart;

class WelcomeView extends React.Component {

  render() {

    var chartData = [
      {"name":"Darron Weissnat IV","BMI":20.72,"age":39,"birthday":"2005-01-03T00:00:00.000Z","city":"East Russel","married":false,"index":0},
      {"name":"Guido Conroy","BMI":25.17,"age":39,"birthday":"1977-04-20T00:00:00.000Z","city":"Scarlettland","married":true,"index":20},
      {"name":"Miss Demond Weissnat V","BMI":21.44,"age":19,"birthday":"2007-06-09T00:00:00.000Z","city":"Savionberg","married":false,"index":21},
      {"name":"Easton Mante","BMI":20.61,"age":43,"birthday":"2007-01-29T00:00:00.000Z","city":"Kutchberg","married":false,"index":22},
      {"name":"Dayton Ebert","BMI":29.88,"age":20,"birthday":"1978-04-27T00:00:00.000Z","city":"West Wiley","married":true,"index":23}
    ]

    var width = 700,
      height = 300,
      margins = {left: 100, right: 100, top: 50, bottom: 50},
      title = "User sample",
      chartSeries = [
        {
          field: 'BMI',
          name: 'BMI',
          color: '#ff7f0e'
        }
      ],
      // your x accessor
      x = function(d) {
        return d.index;
      }

    return (
      <div>
          <div>
            <Chart
              title={title}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              margins= {margins}
            >
              <LineChart
                margins= {margins}
                title={title}
                data={chartData}
                width={width}
                height={height}
                chartSeries={chartSeries}
                x={x}
              />
            </Chart>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WelcomeView;
```

I think I followed everything correctly so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE :**

If I dynamically add another SVG element above the chart element, for example a circle :

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Then the circle appears, and magically the adding of the SVG element kickstarted the rendering process for the charts.

Very confused why this would be happening :(

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: no, I ended up switching to recharts :)

Answer (score 8):

I followed the same steps and initially couldn't get it to display either.

However what I did notice is that in the sample code they list from [gitHub](https://github.com/react-d3/react-d3-example/blob/master/simple/line_user/line_user.js)
they didn't nest LineChart inside Chart (as they do in the instructions). Once I removed the encompassing 'Chart' my graph appeared.

```js
return (
      <LineChart
        //showXGrid={false}
        //showYGrid={false}
        margins= {margins}
        title={title}
        data={chartData}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        chartSeries={chartSeries}
        x={x}
      />
    );
```